# How to setup proxy auth for a wsdl2java ant?

Tags: ant, proxy

I'm trying this:

```
<target name="generate" depends="clean,init">
  <mkdir dir="${source.dir}/generated"/>
  <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <sysproperty key="http.proxyHost" value="proxy.example.com"/>
    <sysproperty key="http.proxyPort" value="8080"/>
    <sysproperty key="http.proxyUser" value="secretUser"/>
    <sysproperty key="http.proxyPassword" value="complexPass"/>
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="${source.dir}/generate"/>
    <arg value="-client"/>
    <arg value="http://example.com/WS?wsdl"/>
    <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

And when I execute the target I get 407 error, auth required

```
Problem parsing 'http://example.com/WS?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://example.com/WS?wsdl
```

I get same error if I set https proxy, and when I don't set proxy I get:

```
Problem parsing 'http://example.com/WS?wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I also try using a incorrect password to verify if as expected 401 error returned, but 407 was returned.

Answer (score 1):

There is no service at `http://example.com/WS?wsdl`. That's just an example web address. You need to enter a real web service URI pointing at a valid WSDL for that service. E.g.

http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?WSDL

Comment: That URL is not real I only hide the url for privacy reasons. Even I prove with [http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?WSDL](http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?WSDL) And I got the same.

Comment: Cool. Sorry. Was just a little misleading. I suspect the problem lies in your proxy settings then. Difficult to offer much advice on this, I'm afraid. Hope you find a resolution for it.